# Django Test: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: django, django-forms

I get the error from the ProductTestCase:

```
...setUp
    department = DepartmentForm(department_name_text=self.department_name)
    ...
...in __init__
    super(DepartmentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 
    'department_name_text'
```

It would be great to know how to fix this issue and why it only occurs when on Foreign keys.

I have added in Department test as well, it works fine.

Thank you for your time.

**Department Test**

```
class DepartmentTestCase(ModelTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        super(DepartmentTestCase, self).setUp()
        self.department_form = self.get_department_form(department_name_text=self.department_name)

    def test_valid_input(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.department_form.is_valid())
```

**Product Test (updated: change to match comment improvement)**

```
class ProductTestCase(ModelTestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        super(ProductTestCase, cls).setUpTestData()

    def setUp(self):
        super(ProductTestCase, self).setUp()

        self.product_data = {'barcode_text': self.barcode
                             }
        department_inst = Department.objects.create(department_name_text=self.department_name) 

        maker_inst = Maker.objects.create(maker_name_text=self.maker_name)

        self.product_data.update({'name_text': department_inst,
                                  'from_maker': maker_inst})

    def test_valid_input(self):
        product_form = ProductForm(self.product_data)

        self.assertTrue(product_form.is_valid())
```

**Department Form**

```
class DepartmentForm(ModelForm):
    field_names = {'department_name_text': 'Department Name'}

    class Meta:
        model = Department
        fields = ['department_name_text']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DepartmentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field, name in self.field_names.items():
            self.fields[field].label = name
```

Comment: Using a form in the `setUp` method looks unnecessary. You could just do `department_inst = Department.objects.create(department_name_text=self.department_name)`, and similar for `maker_inst`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you should not pass `department_name_text` as an argument to the form. This doesn't have anything to do with whether the field is a foreign key or not.

Normally, you pass the POST data to the form using `request.POST`:

```
form = DepartmentForm(request.POST)
```

When you are testing, you should pass a dictionary to the form:

```
department = DepartmentForm({'department_name_text': self.department_name})
```